# Exception while XamlReader.Load(..)

Tags: c#, xaml

i get an Exception during (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(...) which says

```
'Cannot create unknown type 'TextBox'.' Line number '1' and line position '2'.
```

on the following xaml:

```
<TextBox Name="inputMyFirstString" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="test"></TextBox>
```

What did i wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, this is due to [missing namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx#xaml_files). Try

```
<TextBox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" ...
```

Comment: This will work, but adding the namespace to every control in the XAML is not a good idea. Better to define it globally.

Comment: @Winston Smith: i have defined the namespace in my control to which i add the textbox. Where else can i define the namespace globally?

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but I think the "right" answer is still missing.
You can avoid changing your XAML by adding the required namespaces in code:

```
ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("","http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
//etc.

object content = XamlReader.Load(stream, context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the xmlns attribute to the Window element in your XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" ...
```